# Alternate of server polling?

Tags: javascript, http, webserver, long-polling, ajax-polling

**As we know, if running application also manage sessions in main memory then is there any way for server to send responses to all web clients/browsers for new recorded data in a database.**

**Remember**: I have not made any request to server or polling to server for new records update..

**Let server make responses without web request..**

**Objective** :
 No all web browsers making request or polling to server for every certain interval therefore reducing the performance issue with the application memory..

**Am just against of making so many ajax calls from every web client..**

Need your ideas from your past, if experienced similar..

Answer (score 1):

read about websockets and socket.io.
basically with [socket.io](http://socket.io/) you have a connection open between browser (client) and server and server can send data which the client than receives as an event.
the client doesn't need to send a request to get that data, only open the web socket connection.

you can look at socket.io chat example: http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Comment: Hey sagie, need one more help.. pls tell me how to get started with web desktop notification

Comment: there is a notification github project that could help you: https://github.com/ttsvetko/HTML5-Desktop-Notifications. if you are using angular, I wrote one as well: https://github.com/sagiegurari/angular-web-notification

Answer (score 0):

WebSocket is the best and easy solution if you don't want to go through the hassle to learn Angular or others.

Both server-side and client-side can build WebSocket, and it acts as a bridge to transmit data back and forth.

I just created an easy solution for this.

Please check my new library [wsm - WebSocket Manager](https://github.com/jefftham/wsm), it works for both server-side and client-side.

Websocket Server can be built easily; this library includes several useful features.

Comment: Meanwhile I want to know, what should be the optimised way of developing your own chatter tool via web sockets ? Just need anything from you that can be shared. My front end is angularjs and backend with nosejs ..

Comment: I do not have deep knowledge about AngularJs. As i know Angularjs itself can talk to the server directly. You need spend time to research it.

Comment: i got some ideas if you need to implement websocket to build a chatter tool. After you build the websocket server in nodejs, create the socket on client-side when they visit the website or join the chatroom.  After the type the message in the text-box,  fire an on-click event to send the message to websocket server in the back-end. Then, the websocket server should broadcast the message to every connected sockets. So, the instant chat room is built.

Comment: Hey @Sagie need your help, before chat application building want to know socket.io vs xmpp.. should i not go with xmpp for chatter tool and use socket.io for push notifications stuffs only ?

Please explain in brief..

Comment: Yes now i can manage sockets easily but someone needs to shed some light again. 
Actually i want chatter tool and for that i have n questions to ask like where i store all my chats as previous or chat history and hot to share digital files using sockets(chatter tool)..  ?

Comment: the chat history can be stored easily. 1)  (server) it can be stored when data send back to server, write it to a file. 2)  (browser) an on-click event to read text in the text box, write the stream to a file and trigger another on-click event to download it.

Comment: please share some relevant examples as you just taught which looks so much promising to me.. please share more ..